# Tool For Constructing HTTP Requests

Tags: web-services, http, http-headers

I'm looking for the best tool that allows me to construct my own http requests.  Like the firefox addon poster.

Any suggestions.  I'm looking at doing some security testing on webservices.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fiddler2](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is the best tool I know of for that kind of work .. massive amount of features for scripting building requests, as well as storing sessions for later analysis.

Comment: Particularly useful if you want to start by capturing a "normal" session then replay certain requests with changes, but you can also build a request from scratch

Answer (score 2):

[cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) is a nice command-line tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966)
[Apache JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

[soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is great for testing web services.

Answer (score 0):

[WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) from the [Open Web Application Security Project](http://www.owasp.org/).